# Error in Signature Verification using C# on OpenShift

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openshift, rsa, signature

I am not very good in .net but unfortunately need to work on existing .net code where RSA Signature verification is done using Middleware class in Visual Studio. The code works fine in my Visual Studio but fails on OpenShift .net Core 3.1 image with below error:

```
[16:47:16 ERR] Stack Trace :   
  at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , HttpClient , Object )
  at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1) in /_/src/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Dynamic/UpdateDelegates.Generated.cs:line 27
```

Also I see the request path "" does not match the path filter Error in serilogs. If comment (app.UseMiddleware<MSSOMiddleware.MSSOMiddleware>) code works fine in OpenShift but does not verify the sign.

```
        app.UseHsts();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
        //app.UseMiddleware<MSSOMiddleware.MSSOMiddleware>();
        app.UseMvc();
```

As I am not very good in .net could someone help to understand what that error belongs to?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes

Comment: Thank you , i removed "using System.Linq" from MSSOMiddleware.cs file still Openshift throws the same error . what i am not getting is the difference on my Local VS code and OpenShift.

Comment: also the error Seen for this lineMSSOMiddleware.MSSOMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) {"RequestId": "0HM14GKGUAPFG:00000001", "RequestPath": "/api/v1/Data/test", "SpanId": "|1374b14e-4f4e8ff39fe38662.", "TraceId": "1374b14e-4f4e8ff39fe38662", "ParentId": "", "ConnectionId": "0HM14GKGUAPFG"}

Comment: [03:56:34 ERR] Stack Trace :   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , HttpClient , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1) in /_/src/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Dynamic/UpdateDelegates.Generated.cs:line 271
   at MSSOMiddleware.MSSOMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) {"RequestId": "0HM14GKGUAPFG:00000001", "RequestPath": "/api/v1/Data/test", "SpanId": "|1374b14e-4f4e8ff39fe38662.", "TraceId": "1374b14e-4f4e8ff39fe38662", "ParentId": "", "ConnectionId": "0HM14GKGUAPFG"}

Comment: The signature is part of the SSL/TLS validation as part of HTTPS (Secure).   What version of OpenShift are you using (latest 4.4)?  See the configuration guide section "Enabling HTTP strict transport security" on following : https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.4/networking/routes/route-configuration.html#nw-enabling-hsts_route-configuration

Comment: Use following search which may help https://docs.openshift.com/search.html?query=tls

Comment: Application is HTTPS only And OpenShift 3.11. Its about Request coming from IDP with JWT signed and we are verifying the signature with Public key of JWTS.

Comment: Code is working on Local VS and not on OpenShift.  So I would first use a sniffer (wireshark or fiddler) on working VS and check version of TLS that is being used and the http headers in first request.  Then do same on OpenShift.  I just guessing now.  But older version of OpenShift may not be working with the version of SSL/TLS that you are using.  Recently many networks stopped using TLS 1.1 and maybe code only works with TLS 1.1.  Any way comparing with a sniffer may help give additional information.  Also with sniffer verify the encryption mode parameters that are being used.

Comment: finally it was resolved, it was deployment issue on OpenShift.